# OpenAi RateLimitError no matter the input or frequency

Tags: python, openai-api

I set up a small test for the OpenAi API in Python:

```
import openai
openai.api_key = "Secret Key"

prompt = "Hello"
model = "text-davinci-003"
response = openai.Completion.create(engine=model, prompt=prompt, max_tokens=50)

generated_text = response.choices[0].text
print(generated_text)
```

No matter the input, even an empty string, will throw the "openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.". I waited for about 10 hours until i ran the python script again, but still the error occurs.

When I look at my usage on OpenAi's website, the key is pretty much untouched. I still got my 18$ to use. I even tried a key from a friend, but it did not solve anything. I can't even seem to find a solution on the internet.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is an expiration date on the 18 dollars you are given, I just missed that. The expiration date can be seen under "usage".